# Simplify a long boolean expression

Tags: java, boolean

Im pretty new to this plattform  and well I have a trouble regarding boolean expression in my CS-class. I have to simplifly this boolean expression and have no clue how to do this.

double x ;
double y  ;

**boolean b = ( (y < -x) ^ (5 * x >= y) ) && ( (x < -y) != (x >= y * 0.2) )**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming pure math, `y < -x` is equivalent to `x < -y`, `5 * x >= y` is equivalent to `x >= y * 0.2` and `whateverBoolean1 ^ whateverBoolean2` is equivalent to `whateverBoolean1 != whateverBoolean2`. Hence you can omit any side of `&&` operator.

I am neglecting freaks of floating point arithmetics (0.2 is not precise number so some counterexample that original and simplified expression are not equivalent could be perhaps found after some effort.)